# Lista horario en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que generar una lista de horas comprendidas entre las 10:00 y 19:30 en minutos de 30min con un bucle for. (ej. 10:00 - 10:30 - 11:00......)

De momento lo tengo hecho así pero no me parece que esté bien hecho.

```
for (var i=10; i<20; i++){

    document.write(i + ":00 " + i + "" + ":30" + " ");          
}
```

Comment: y cual es el problema  en como lo estas generando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el tipo [Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) y trabajar sobre los minutos. Luego mostrar hora y minutos. Por ejemplo:

```js
var now = new Date('2018-09-28T10:00:00');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < 19; i++){
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30);
    console.log(now.getHours() + ":" + ("00" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El código hace lo que quieres.

puede se puede leer mejor el código así:

```
for (var i=10; i<20; i++){

  document.write(i + ":00 " + i + ":30 " );          
}
```

o así:

```
for (var i=10; i<20; i++){

  document.write(i + ":00 "); 
  document.write(i + ":30 ");  
}
```